# Why does using User.IsInRole() always return false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identity

I use User.IsInRole() to check that after logging in, users with the admin role will go straight to the admin page, if they don't have the admin role, they will go to another page. However, User.IsInRole() always returns false
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6ef1.png)]

```
   var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
       UserManager<AppUser> usermanager;
       if  (User.IsInRole("Administrator")||User.IsInRole("Admin"))
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tours", new { area = "Admin" });
          
       }
       else
       {
           return RedirectToPage(returnUrl);
       }
```

I want to use it to check that after logging in, users with the admin role will immediately go to the admin page

Comment: shouldn’t it be Administrators (note the plural)?

Comment: no , i check it , it is "administrator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `User.IsInRole()`, you can also use the `UserManager` to check roles.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
if (user != null)
{
    var isAdmin = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Administrator") || await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
    if (isAdmin)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tours", new { area = "Admin" });
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToPage(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method:userManager.IsInRoleAsync has been introduced in my answer, and my answer is earlier than yours.

Comment: ``Qing Guo`` : Okay, enjoy then.

Comment: I tried doing the same as you, but when I log in with an admin account, the first time the User will be null, the second time I log in it will say that the page cannot be accessed and the third time it will be able to access the page. admin. admin

Answer (score 0):

> Why does using User.IsInRole() always return false

When a user authenticates using their username and password,and successfully logged in, they're issued a token, containing an authentication ticket that can be used for authentication and authorization. The token is stored as a cookie that's sent with every request the client makes. Generating and validating this cookie is performed by the Cookie Authentication Middleware. The middleware serializes a user principal into an encrypted cookie. On subsequent requests, the middleware validates the cookie, recreates the principal, and assigns the principal to the `User` property.

After you successfully logged in( Complete login action, not in the current login post action), on subsequent requests, you will  get  User.IsInRole() in another  Authorize action.That's the reason why using User.IsInRole() always return false.

> I use User.IsInRole() to check that after logging in, users with the
> admin role will go straight to the admin page,

You can try to use [UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(TUser, String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.isinroleasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  to check the User role like:

```
if  (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(appUser, "Administrator")||await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(appUser, "Admin"))
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tours", new { area = "Admin" });
          
       }
```

Comment: I tried doing the same as you, but when I log in with an admin account, the first time the User will be null, the second time I log in it will say that the page cannot be accessed and the third time it will be able to access the page. admin. admin

Comment: @đạobảnh  In my explaination I said , 'on subsequent requests, you will get User.IsInRole() in another Authorize action.That's the reason why using User.IsInRole() always return false."

Comment: So is there any way to log in directly to the admin page? I did this and still had to log in 3 times
---------
     var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
     if (user != null)
     {
         var isAdmin = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Administrator") || await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
         if (isAdmin)
         {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tours", new { area = "Admin" });
         }
         else
         {
             return RedirectToPage(returnUrl);
         }
     }
---------

Comment: @đạobảnh   Do you set a breakpoint at `var isAdmin = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Administrator") || await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin");` ? What the value of isAdmin ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding your roles as claims?

This is how I am using in my projects:

```
// set default claims
var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Username),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
        new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, user._id.ToString())
    };

// set user role claims
foreach (var roleName in user.Roles)
{
    Claim roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName);
    claims.Add(roleClaim);
}

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    //AllowRefresh = <bool>,
    // Refreshing the authentication session should be allowed.

    ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
    // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
    // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
    // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

    IsPersistent = Input.RememberMe,
    // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
    // multiple requests. Required when setting the 
    // ExpireTimeSpan option of CookieAuthenticationOptions 
    // set with AddCookie. Also required when setting 
    // ExpiresUtc.

    IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
    // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

    //RedirectUri = <string>
    // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http 
    // redirect response value.
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    authProperties);
```